# Exec a subprocess : pass PYTHONPATH to the subprocess

Tags: tcl

When I am executing a Python script and ensure that PYTHONPATH is properly set to refer depedency modules. Within the Python code I call a TCL script which again calls a Python script like below:

```
if {[catch {exec {*}[auto_execok python] [file nativename [file join [file dirname [info script]] my.py ]] } result] == 0 } {
     puts "Executed successfully $result"
 } else {
     puts "Error $result"
     return error
}
```

I am successfully able to execute the Python script **my.py** externally but when executed from the TCL script it gives issues. Somehow I find that it is cause the PYTHONPATH is not being passed properly while calling the Python script since my.py refers to depdency Python modules.

How can I pass the PYTHONPATH in exec command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `PYTHONPATH` is an environment variable. They're manipulated through the `env` global variable:

```
# You might be able to set this once for your whole script
set python_path {C:/Python/3.6/wherever C:/Users/me/Python/3.6/wherever}
# Transform a Tcl list into the right format that Python expects
set ::env(PYTHONPATH) [join [lmap p $python_path {file nativename $p}] \
    $::tcl_platform(pathSeparator)]

# Split this out for a shorter line length. ;-)
set my_py [file join [file dirname [info script]] my.py]

if {[catch {exec {*}[auto_execok python] [file nativename $my_py]} result] == 0 } {
    puts "Executed successfully $result"
} else {
    puts "Error $result"
    return error
}
```

In Tcl 8.5, you don't have `lmap` or the `pathSeparator` element of `tcl_platform` and instead would do something like this:

```
foreach p $python_path {
    if {[info exist ::env(PYTHONPATH)]} {
        # Assume Windows
        append ::env(PYTHONPATH) ";" [file nativename $p]
    } else {
        set ::env(PYTHONPATH) [file nativename $p]
    }
}
```

You could also hardcode the values if they're just one or two elements. Remember that backslashes (`\`) are significant to Tcl, so put the string in `{`…`}` if you're doing that.

```
set ::env(PYTHONPATH) {C:\Python\3.6\wherever;C:\Users\me\Python\3.6\wherever}
```

That's not particularly viable for anything redistributable… but works for one's own scripts.

Comment: it seems lmap is not available in TCL 8.5 - though one question can we pass the PYTHON path like [auto_execok python --pythonpath $systempypath] ...

Comment: Not inside the `auto_execok` call.